# ways to make my chatbot project embeddable?

Tags: javascript, html, django, chatbot, openai-api

I have build a chatbot using openai' s api and the django framework. I hosted this chatbot online using railway' s platform, it works just fine. Now, i want to make it embeddable on other web sites.
I want to share the bot to other websites, like botpress does, just using  tags and just a few lines of code. This is the link to the github repo where my project is hosted : [text](https://github.com/Iulian19768/chatbotpublic).

I tried using  but it' s just ugly, i takes space on the web site even when it doesn' t have to.

Comment: have you looked into the `<iframe src="...">` element and then sharing the code to that? that's what some websites use in these scenarios

Comment: I have tried, but it load' s all the site, i just wan to load only the chatbot and it' s functionality